# Uso do "print()" vazio em vez de "\n"

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação

É errado utilizar `print()` para dar um espaço em vez do caracter `\n`?

Exemplo:

```py
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))

if idade > 0 and idade < 10:
    print('Você é uma criança.')
elif idade >= 10 and idade < 20:
    print('Você é um jovem.')
elif idade >= 20 and idade < 40:
    print('Você é um adulto.')
elif idade >= 40 and idade < 60:
    print('Você está na meia-idade.')
elif idade > 60:
    print('Você está na velhice.')
```

Colocando um `print()` antes das condições:

```py
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))

print()

if idade > 0 and idade < 10:
    print('Você é uma criança.')
elif idade >= 10 and idade < 20:
    print('Você é um jovem.')
elif idade >= 20 and idade < 40:
    print('Você é um adulto.')
elif idade >= 40 and idade < 60:
    print('Você está na meia-idade.')
elif idade > 60:
    print('Você está na velhice.')
```

Colocando um `\n` no começo de todos os `prints`:

```py
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))

if idade > 0 and idade < 10:
    print('\nVocê é uma criança.')
elif idade >= 10 and idade < 20:
    print('\nVocê é um jovem.')
elif idade >= 20 and idade < 40:
    print('\nVocê é um adulto.')
elif idade >= 40 and idade < 60:
    print('\nVocê está na meia-idade.')
elif idade > 60:
    print('\nVocê está na velhice.')
```

Opto por usar o `print()`, pois acho mais simples. Mas isso seria válido? Outros programadores fazem o mesmo? Ou o ideal seria colocar `\n` em cada `print` para dar um espaço, mesmo após um código com várias condições?

Comment: O colega já respondeu de forma adequada. Gostaria de salientar que não existem perguntas "besta", besta é quem não faz perguntas. As dúvidas são inerentes ao processo de aprendizagem e não importa se é um iniciante ou um senior developer, dúvidas sempre existirão.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De fato não tem problema. Outra alternativa seria você apenas definir o valor de uma variável com as suas condições e chamar a função `print` apenas uma vez. Isso seria outra aplicação do que o Maniero comentou na resposta dele sobre a repetição de código. Hoje você está enviando o resultado para a saída, mas se precisasse alterar isso para salvar em um arquivo, por exemplo, seriam vários lugares do código para fazer a mesma alteração; fazendo apenas uma chamada seria apenas uma linha alterada:

```
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))

if idade > 0 and idade < 10:
    mensagem = 'Você é uma criança.'
elif idade >= 10 and idade < 20:
    mensagem = 'Você é um jovem.'
elif idade >= 20 and idade < 40:
    mensagem = 'Você é um adulto.'
elif idade >= 40 and idade < 60:
    mensagem = 'Você está na meia-idade.'
elif idade > 60:
    mensagem = 'Você está na velhice.'
else:
    mensagem = 'Não sei o que fazer com este valor.'

print(f'\n{mensagem}')
```

> **Nota:** adicionei o `else` para garantir que `mensagem` seja sempre definida independente das condições (`idade` negativa, por exemplo).

Vale citar também que em Python não necessita fazer a condição:

```
idade > 0 and idade < 10
```

Você pode fazer:

```
0 < idade < 10
```

Que fica muito mais legível aos humanos. Desta forma, ficaria:

```
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))

if 0 < idade < 10:
    mensagem = 'Você é uma criança.'
elif 10 <= idade < 20:
    mensagem = 'Você é um jovem.'
elif 20 <= idade < 40:
    mensagem = 'Você é um adulto.'
elif 40 <= idade < 60:
    mensagem = 'Você está na meia-idade.'
elif idade > 60:
    mensagem = 'Você está na velhice.'
else:
    mensagem = 'Não sei o que fazer com este valor.'

print(f'\n{mensagem}')
```

Answer (score 7):

Não tem problema algum. Na verdade você está pensando como um programador e evitando repetições desnecessárias. Talvez não veja muito isso porque algumas pessoas não pensam como programadores e outras só copiam códigos de outros ou de si mesmo, então a cópia cria sem querer repetições. Não digo que este caso faça tanta diferença assim, mas se a semântica é "pular uma linha independente de qual condição caia". Em uma situação diferente talvez a decisão seria outra. Não existe regra mágica, tem que entender o problema e fazer o que ele pede.

Faça um exercício, pense em que problemas esperaria ter se fizer de um jeito ou de outro. Saber o porque é mais importante que saber o que fazer.

Dá para simplificar as condições dos `if`s.

```
idade = int(input('Quantos anos você tem?'))
print()
if idade < 1:
     print('Não sei o que fazer com este valor.')
elif idade < 10:
   print('Você é uma criança.')
elif idade < 20:
     print('Você é um jovem.')
elif idade < 40:
     print('Você é um adulto.')
elif idade < 60:
    print('Você está na meia-idade.')
else:
     print('Você está na velhice.')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/omiTbv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Printpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/Print.py).